# Cannot join column using inverseJoin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a table called `Freelance` which contains `province_id` column, that column is linked to the `geo_province_entity` table which has the following structure:

```
id | region_id | name
```

I'm trying to return the region when I retrieve a freelance, so I did:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\PageBundle\Entity\GeoRegionEntity")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="geo_province_entity",
*     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
*     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="province_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
*   )
*/
protected $region;
```

I used `JoinTable` to link the `geo_province_entity` that contains the `region_id`, and tried to link the `id` of `get_region_entity`.

Seems that isn't enough, infact I get this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'f0_.region_id' in 'field list'

Meanwhile I doesn't have any issue retrieve the province:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\PageBundle\Entity\GeoProvinceEntity", inversedBy="geo_province_entity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="province_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $province;
```

Essentially for retrieve the region name, I have to create a relationship through the `geo_province_entity` using the `region_id` column, is there any way to do this?

TABLE STRUCTURE:

**freelance**

```
| id | province_id |
```

**geo_province_entity**

```
| id | name | region_id |
```

**geo_region_entity**

```
| id | name | nation_id |
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get the name with ->getProvince()->getRegion()->getName()?

Can you pass doctrine's "validate-schema" ? JoinTable with a OneToOne seems odd to me. Also OneToOne to link a freelance and a region seems restraining. You just want to get the region's name from the freelance entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JoinTable` is usually used for a ManyToMany relation and this table contains only 2 fields for relations, it's not impossible to create additional fields for a relation table in ManyToMany. It's necessary to create additional relations.

Freelance

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\PageBundle\Entity\GeoProvinceEntity")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="province_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $geoProvinceEntity;
```

GeoProvinceEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\PageBundle\Entity\GeoRegionEntity") // or OneToOne
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $geoRegionEntity;
```

The region entity you can get by freelance by:

```
$freelance->getGeoProvinceEntity()->geoRegionEntity();
```